# How can i block web mail URL from public access?

Tags: email, web, web-hosting

I am looking for a solution to block the web mail url from public access.

For. e.g:  http://mail.sample.com/ or http://sample.com/webmail

I need to block this url from public access.How can i do it?

Comment: define "public"? on what criteria do you want to allow access?

Comment: if i will type http://mail.example.com it will got to the email client page.I need to block the world from accessing this url.

Comment: If you want to block it from the whole world, unplug your server and dump it in a bath.

Comment: i know .but client is asking these type of questions.They want to block this URL. When anybody take the URL ,there should be a message like not accessible or not found.

Comment: Yes... but *how do they want to determine* who gets to see the actual content? If you want to block it from **everybody** then just don't have it exist. If you want to block it from **only some people** then you need to describe the *rules* for differentiating between those who are allowed to see it and those who aren't. Any solution people suggest is going to be dependent on what those rules are, so if you don't state them you won't get clear, meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to ask for authentication & or authorization on that page and check for it on your code depending on what framework u use. can be basic authentication, digest authentication, forms-based authentication, etc.

otherwise u may also restrict the server to only accept specific IP addresses.